# PHP. cURL error

Tags: php, curl

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
$states = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

returns Failed to connect to 178.62.8.233 port 1080: Connection refused

Comment: None of that code should try to connect to port 1080. Do you have a proxy configured?

Comment: I don't think `178.62.8.233` has anything to do with Google.

Comment: I checked proxy settings. They were set to auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
$states = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($states);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I don't know if it works, but I found the solution. I just use file_get_contents()

Comment: good jobs mate. if you want to explore more request like set header, coookie, proxy, etc. use curl is recomendation.

Comment: I found http_proxy environment variable with a value of 178.62.8.233. So I think that was the actual reason for that response